# Packaging Windows 8 App Data File

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing a Win 8 app and I would like to include a data file with the app.  The data file will be unique for each user so it should really reside under /Users/(user)/AppData/Packages/(MyAppPackage)

Is is possible to do that with a deployment/installation package, and if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CMIIW,

You cannot include the data file which your package, unless you put your data file in the application directory / installed directory, then after the first run, you can move it (the data file) to the /Users/(user)/AppData

I believe you will not save sensitive data to the Users/(user)/AppData, since the user can access to the folder with Windows Explorer easily, or if you must save it to AppData, I suggest you to encrypt your data first.

Cheers
Yusak Setiawan
http://apptivate.ms/apps/1271/mathboard

Comment: That kinda sucks, but I guess I can work around it by copying as you said.  Nice app BTW.